# SOLR Date range

Tags: datetime, solr, range

I have to make an ezfind search page with date functions. For the SOLR filter I tried to use something like this: attr_publish_date_dt:[NOW-6MONTH TO NOW] but I don't get any result. 
If I use it this way attr_publish_date_dt:[* TO NOW], it works. But all queries without an asterisk on the left hand don't work.

attr_publish_date_dt contains a unix timestamp so I also tried to use 2 timestamps from the attr_publish_date_dt:[* TO NOW] result, instead of [NOW-6MONTH TO NOW], but then I get also no results.

Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance
Frank

Comment: Which solr version? Are you using TrieDateField? `[NOW-6MONTH TO NOW]` works fine for me in solr 4.2.1 with date field definition `<fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>`

Comment: we use SOLR 2.2, because the ez publish version we use, isn't supporting a higher version of SOLR.

Answer (score 0):

Date searches are supported on a date field. You will need to define a field of that type, and submit dates in [ISO-8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html

If you cannot properly format the timestamp before sending it to Solr, you may be able to use a DateFormatTransformer or a ScriptTransformer to do the job.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#DateFormatTransformer
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer

Comment: thanks for your answer, we will check our import scripts to fix the problem.